# how to get the index of the li clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Just using javascript, need to get the index of the li that's clicked with the following listener:

```
var ulList = document.getElementById('todo-list');

ulList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if( e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {

   //IS THERE A WAY INSIDE HERE TO GET THE INDEX OF THE li clicked
       e.target.parentNode.remove(); 
   } 
});
```

each li looks like:

```
<li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="todo[]">
   <span class="centerSpan" style="text-decoration: none;">abc</span>
   <button class="rightButton">X</button>
</li>
```

Comment: If you explain why we can probably tell you a better way to do what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the target (button, in this case) call [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get a reference to your li element

```
var li = e.target.closest('li');
```

Then get an array reference of your UL's children by using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and passing in the [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) HTMLCollection

```
var nodes = Array.from( ulList.children );
//or if you want to not depend on externally defined variables
var nodes = Array.from( li.closest('ul').children );
```

Finally call [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the index

```
var index = nodes.indexOf( li );
```

If wanting to support old browsers will need to polyfill for methods like [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)